# When Sauron saw Frodo at Mount Doom, why doesn't he do anything?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-return-of-the-king

In the film (3.15), the Eye of Sauron sees Frodo on the corner of Mount Doom.

Maybe he didn't think that they are the ones trying to destroy the ring, but at least he sees someone who is a stranger in his land.

Shouldn't he react this situation in some way?

Edit:
I am talking about this scene:

[image]

Comment: In the books Sauron (who is *not* a giant eyeball) doesn't "see" them until  Frodo claims the ring.

Comment: @ibid Your comment also is worthy of at least 1000 up votes - but that too wouldn't be enough... But PJ. I think that says it all.

Answer (score 7):

> And far away, as Frodo put on the Ring and claimed it for his own, even in Sammath Naur the very heart of his realm, the Power in Barad-dûr was shaken, and the Tower trembled from its foundations to its proud and bitter crown. The Dark Lord was suddenly aware of him, and his Eye piercing all shadows looked across the plain to the door that he had made; and the magnitude of his own folly was revealed to him in a blinding flash, and all the devices of his enemies were at last laid bare. Then his wrath blazed in consuming flame, but his fear rose like a vast black smoke to choke him. For he knew his deadly peril and the thread on which his doom now hung.
>
> From all his policies and webs of fear and treachery, from all his stratagems and wars his mind shook free; and throughout his realm a tremor ran, his slaved quailed, and his armies halted, and his captains suddenly steerless, bereft of will, wavered and despaired. For they were forgotten. The whole mind and purpose of the Power that wielded them was now bent with overwhelming force upon the Mountain. At his summons, wheeling with a rending cry, in a last desperate race there flew, faster than the winds, the Nazgûl, the Ringwraiths, and with a storm of wings they hurtled southwards to Mount Doom.
>
> <sub>— *TRotK*</sub>

He did respond — he sent the Nazgûl. But he was too late, the Ring was eaten, and he was defeated.

Comment: I am not talking about that scene.I edited the question.İf you look , you will understand what scene I am talking

Comment: @leth I've never watched the movies. What is that scene?

Comment: @leth my point is, **he wasn't aware of them until Frodo claimed the ring for himself.** Maybe it's different in the movies.

Comment: "The ring was *eaten"?*

Comment: @Joel. Just a joke. It was bitten off. :P

Comment: @Mithrandir I hope you still haven't watched them? If you have I feel sorry for you. I tried really, really, and I really really really mean really, hard to like them but every time I tried it got worse. I can't watch them now they're that bad.

Answer (score 6):

**The Book**

In the book he doesn't spot Frodo until it is too late because he is focused upon the fight between his forces and the armies of Gondor/Rohan who although outnumbered are still interesting enough to warrant watching. It is like if I was watching a film in which I knew the outcome (the fight) instead of two ants crawling across the floor (the Hobbits). Also Sauron wanted to watch the defeat of his greatest enemies: the Númenóreans and Gandalf.

In the book he only notices Frodo when he claims the Ring.

**The Film**

In the film he sees them but presumably doesn't know they have the Ring and decides to ignore them for now and focus on more interesting things. They will probably get killed by orcs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch it again, you will notice that the Nazgûl turn around to Mount Doom and attempt to take Frodo out. Now Sauron no longer has a powerful physical form  (see the four fingers passage in the book) at that time and therefore cannot do anything about Frodo. So, he *does* react by calling the Nazgûl's attention to the situation, but he himself cannot do anything.

Comment: But it happen when the ring is thrown into Mount Doom not the eye see the Frodo.

Comment: But he does have a body. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/why-didnt-sauron-fight-in-the-final-battle

Comment: "or, if he does as was claimed by Smeagol (see the four fingers passage in the book), it is severely weakened"

Comment: Even if he does, it is nowhere near significant enough or powerful enough to do anything about Frodo/Sam.

Comment: İt doesn't matter whether he has a physical form or not .He can easily give order to his servants.

Comment: Sauron was distracted (by the armies of Gondor/Rohan). Doubtless there were things crawling in Mordor that were not all known to Sauron, he might have easily dismissed what he saw and just focused northwest, on the battle.

Comment: But they have already out of number , so if it didn't pay attention  , it won't be a problem and he had already known that the ring had been tried to destroy .Therefore ,the reason for he doesn't react can't be due to the armies at Black gate.

Comment: @Leth The logic in the film doesn't work that well.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Oh but it does matter. Because the films are so utterly wrong it's sickening to watch. Not to mention that Tolkien stated that if the Nazgûl were able to delay him (he supposed they wouldn't take him or the Ring straight away) then he (Frodo) would soon see Sauron and he would be utterly destroyed - unless he threw himself into the fire, of course. And you're also wrong because he didn't know until Frodo actually claimed it at Sammath Naur; he imagined Aragorn had the Ring.